# Searching for whether combination of data set B exist in dataset A

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, match

I am trying to determine if data Excel file B is correct relative to A. Both files have the same headers except for File B, there is a unique ID attached which I need. There can be several rows of B that correspond to a single row of A. Meaning to say file A contains unique rows and B contains multiple entries of A with a Unique ID for each row. Is there any way to automate the checking process using Excel formulas or VBA? I need to highlight the rows in B that do not correctly match its respective row in A.

***Reference Dataset A:***

[image]

***Reference Dataset B:***

[image]

I need a formula to search file A for the combination and not just one row...E.g row 400 on File A may contain the combination I want the formula to see that row 3 in File B is the same combination and return the yes or formula to see that the combination does not exist in rows 3 through 200 and return a NO and highlight it

Is there a way for me to automate checking? If the data combination in each row cannot be found in reference File A, I need to highlight it. This is a HR file, Drilling down from Macro to Micro organization breakdown.

https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/897552-formula-checking-if-a-combination-of-cells-exists-in-the-range.html similar to this issue

Comment: Sounds like a job for `countifs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are desperate for help as your nickname suggests, you shouldn't ignore peoples suggestions. As i said in the comments `COUNTIFS` can do that.

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$4,C8,$B$2:$B$4,D8,$C$2:$C$4,E8,$D$2:$D$4,F8,$E$2:$E$4,G8,$F$2:$F$4,H8,$G$2:$G$4,I8)>0,"correct","wrong")
```

[image]

The condition of the `IF`-function can be used in conditional formatting to highlight wrong lines with color.